# pandas read_sql with parameters needs string or byte object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have looked at various answers and none of the syntax is working for me. I am using the following code in Python 3.5:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(os.getlogin()) --this part works fine
sql = text('select var1 as "nameM" ' \
              'from Table1 where ' \
              'col1 = :le ' \
              'and col2 = :t ' \
              'and col3Date between :stDt and :enDt')
data = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params = {'le':'S', 't':'HEN', 'stDt':'06-NOV-17', 'enDt':'24-NOV-17'})
```

I have tried various other configurations also and I keep getting the following error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: expecting string or bytes object
```

Comment: You've mixed SQLAlchemy and raw DB-API. cx_Oracle has no idea what to do with a `text()` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using a plain string for your SQL query? Unwrap the `text()` function from your query.

References:

[SQLAlchemy text](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text)

[pd.read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)